# How can I prevent clipping of 2 backgrounds while using the CSS property Contain?

Tags: css, clipping

I want a background at the very top of the page and at the very bottom of the page. Using this CSS gives me the correct effect but it clips the images together at certain resolutions. Is there a way to stop the clipping effect?

```
body{
position:static;
background-image:url(images/header.png), url(images/footer.png);
background-size:contain, contain;
background-position:center top, center bottom;
background-repeat:no-repeat, no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Can you place a sample on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? This will help easily visualize the issue you're having.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what the images look like and how they interact with each other as the window size varies.  Why don't you create a demo using jsbin or jsfiddle, that might raise some interest in your question.

Comment: I'm very curious what sort of images you're using, and what behavior you want as an alternative to overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

I cheated a little bit by swapping images, but here's my solution so far: http://jsbin.com/otuvuj/1

Is this the effect you're going for?